# Create MySQL JOIN from the same table (parent_title from parent_id)

Tags: mysql, sql

I wonder what is the most simple way to achieve the below result?

*table_companies*

```
co_id | co_parent_id | co_title
------|--------------|----------
1       0              name1
2       1              name2
3       1              name3
```

**The RESULT:**

```
Parent_Title    Title
(none)          name1
name1           name2
name1           name3
```

**UPDATE:** I know this should be implemented with LEFT JOIN but honestly, I'm exhausted and haven't played w queries for a long time...

Help is much appreciated.

**SOLUTION (provided by D-Shih and Florian):**

//LEFT JOIN

```
SELECT t2.co_title AS Parent_Title, t1.co_title AS Title 
    FROM table_companies t1 
    LEFT JOIN table_companies t2 ON t1.co_parent_id = t2.co_id
```

//RIGHT JOIN

```
SELECT t2.co_title AS Parent_Title, t1.co_title AS Title 
    FROM tb_companies t1 
    RIGHT JOIN tb_companies t2 ON t2.co_id = t1.co_parent_id
```

Comment: Hint:  `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need self `RIGHT JOIN`

```
SELECT t2.co_title 'Title',t1.co_title 'Parent_Title'
FROM T t1 
RIGHT JOIN T t2 on t1.co_id  = t2.co_parent_id
```

sqlfidde:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ab8fbf/8

Comment: Thank you D-Shih for *data sample* and *Right Join* implementation.

Comment: It's my pleasure:)

Answer (score 2):

You have to join the table on itself. Try:

```
SELECT t2.co_title as Parent_Title, t1.co_title as Title 
FROM table_companies t1 
LEFT JOIN table_companies t2 ON t1.co_parent_id = t2.co_id
```

Comment: Thank you Florian. Suggested correction t1.Title => t1.co_title AS Title. Otherwise error is thrown.